# creating own classes in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, class

I am trying to make a own class in CodeIgniter and therefore I have made a file in the folder

> libraries

This class is called

> Menu

And it contains a class to create a navigation bar for my website. this class is like

```
class Menu {

    public function draw($menu) {
        $CI =& get_instance();

        $output = '';
        foreach ($menu as $key => $value) {
            $output .= "<li>";

            if (is_array($value)) {

                if (strpos($key, '|') !== false) {
                    $param = explode('|', $key);
                    $output .= anchor($param[1], $param[0]);
                } else {
                    $output .= anchor('#', $key);
                }

                $output .= PHP_EOL."<ul>".PHP_EOL;
                $output .= draw($value);
                $output .= "</ul>".PHP_EOL."</li>".PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                $output .= anchor($key, $value, $CI->uri->slash_segment(1, 'leading') == $key ? 'class="active"' : '');
                $output .= "</li>".PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
```

I have put this class in my config file as autoload under libraries

> $autoload['libraries'] = array('menu');

When I call the class to use it I do this

```
    <?php 
    $m = new Menu();
    echo $m->draw($menu);
    ?>
```

But unfortunately I get this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function draw() in /Users/username/Sites/infinity2.0/application/libraries/Menu.php on line 22

Line 22 is $output .= draw($value);

But I don't know how to solve this I think its because of calling its own method again.. any help is welcome and appreciated. :)

Comment: It's nice that you're creating a library for this. it makes me feel ;)

Comment: And remember, once you load the CI library, you can get access to its methods by using `$this->libraryName->method();`. In this case: `$this->menu->draw();`

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out with the documentation from CI website. Only thing I am thinking now of is where to store the menu array hardcoded ( don't use database yet )

Comment: Take a look at Language library, or Config library at CI user guide. your choice ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

`$output .= draw($value);`

to

`$output .= $this->draw($value);`

`$this` refers to the current object, so if you want to recursively call `draw()` within itself, you need to use it to refer to it..

You might want to read the explanation from the php.net website: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Hey thanks! this did the trick :) gonna mark it as right answer in 8 minutes when possible cheers mate!

Comment: No worries. Good luck. I'd highly recommend you read on the ref docs if you're not too familiar with OOP in PHP..